# a few milisecond red screen awaiting api data

Tags: flutter, dart

im using PageView then it contains form with multiple survey form and the form from async await fetching api, when i enter the a few milisecond red screen awaiting api data then it return normal

api fetching code

```
 void getSurveyData() async {
        surveyData = await http.post(
          'survey-pre-mitsu/form-detail',
          body: {
            "survey_form_header_id": surveyPages['idx'],
          },
        ).then(
          (res) {
            return res['data'];
          },
        );
        setState(() {});
      }
```

my Widget Form code

```
 for (var i = 0; i < surveyData.length; i++)
            AdditionalForm(
              questionLabel: surveyData[i]['label'],
              questionType: surveyData[i]['type'],
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean state variable, update it before and after calling api.

```
class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {

  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_loading) {
      // return your loading view
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    
    // or return your normal view
    return Container();
  }

  void getSurveyData() async {
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    
    surveyData = await http.post(
      'survey-pre-mitsu/form-detail',
      body: {
        "survey_form_header_id": surveyPages['idx'],
      },
    );
    
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }
  
}
```

Comment: already do that and it doesn't works, i thinks its the problem with how i call the widget but i didn't understand

Comment: share complete code for your widget